# Heroku warning: django.request not found

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-cms

I need some help. cant find a solution after 3 full days. I'm having this error shown on heroku- `warning:django.request not found`.

I suppose this relates to static files and have done the below:

a) `heroku run ls -l project/`

[image]

--> the static folder here contains css, js, img, vendor files. As static folder appears in heroku, this looks correct?

b) `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput`

--> 0 static files copied to '/app/static', 1115 unmodified. I think something could be wrong here?

c) followed all deployment steps in django, django cms, aldryn and heroku. Hence I think settings, wsgi should be correct.

The guides have been pretty silent on urls.py so I suspect my errors could be:

a) potential error 1?

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^tools/$',views.tickervalu, name='tools'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),     
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,)
    ]
```

b) potential error 2?

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
     'aldryn_boilerplates.staticfile_finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
 ]

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Thanking you in advance. Please let me know if more information is needed, really appreciate it.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the error in your logs is actually `WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /` which means there's no url registered for your root path `/`. It would be helpful to see `urls.py` of the `cms` module as included via `include('cms.urls')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Root path / is in include('cms.urls'). I manage to find the problem which was to change BASE_DIR to os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).

Comment: Changing `__file__` to `file` doesn't make sense and should throw an error as `file` is not defined in your `settings.py`.

Comment: It's `__file__` . My comment got auto formatted. I know why now, got to use ` `. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! You mean you changed the second call of `os.path.dirname` to `os.path.abspath`. Good catch. That makes sense. Use backticks to avoid formatting in code snippets: --> `